# Compilation Error in Perl problems in accessing attributes of an object

Tags: perl

I've written a couple of perl wrapper modules for a C# Tool. The idea is that the script will pass a device name, port number and server address which is used to establish a communication socket. When I write a script to use these modules I get a Compilation Failed in require error

```
"Can't call method "_serveraddr" on an undefined value at Device.pm line 23.
Compilation failed in require at Launch.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Launch.pl line 11."
```

Launch.pl

```
use Device;
use System;
my ( $serverAddress, $port, $reportFile ) = @_;
my $System = new System($serverAddress, $port);
my $dut = new Device('DEV',127.0.0.1,5000);
```

Device.pm

```
package Device;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Command;
use Comm;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = {
        _device     => shift,
        _serveraddr => shift,
        _port       => shift

    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}


my $SockObj = Comm->new( $self->_serveraddr, $self->_port );
my $ComObj = Comm->new();

sub Action1 {

    my ( $self, $x, $y ) = @_;

    my $tmp = {
        'hash1'   => 'Command',
        'value1'        => $x,
        'value2'        => $y,
        'Device' => $self->{_device}
    };
    $InputRequest = $ComObj->CreateInputString($tmp);
    $SockObj->WriteInfo($InputRequest);
    my $Response = $SockObj->ReadData();
    $ComObj->TapResponse($Response);
}
```

System.pm

```
package System;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Comm;
use Command;

my $SockObj = Comm->new();
my $ComObj = Command->new();

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = {
        _serveraddr => shift,
        _port => shift

    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

Could someone please help..I have no clue how to move forward..Please let me know if the question is unclear..

I think the problem is that, in this line

```
my $SockObj = Comm->new( $self->_serveraddr, $self->_port );
```

$self contains an undefined value. How do I fix that?? Moroever, I'm new to perl and I don't know if we can acess the attributes of an object with a hash.

Answer (score 3):

Line 21 is this:

```
my $SockObj = Comm->new( $self->_serveraddr, $self->_port );
```

And that will fail for several different reasons:

1. `$self` is not declared so your `use strict` should cause an error: 'Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name at x.pm line 21.' due to your `use strict;` (but leave that `use strict;` there!).
2. `$self` is not defined, hence the error that you're reporting. You'll have to instantiate a Device before you can call methods on it.
3. `_serveraddr` is not a method on Device, it is an attribute. You'd want to say `$self->{_serveraddr}` to access the attribute value or, better, write an accessor method for it. Same goes for `_port`.

Comment: Additionally, in `Launch.pl`, 127.0.0.1 is not what you think it is.